# Increase UIwebView font size javascript issue

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a UIwebView inside a `UIScrollView`. I used this jscript to increase the font size of the `UIwebview`. it works fine but it cuts some of the text at the bottom of the page and its unable to scroll to the bottom.

here is the code i used to increase the font size:

```
 - (void)pushIncreaseFont:(id)sender
    {

    int fontSize = 150;
    NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc]     initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'",     fontSize];
    [LabelNewsContent stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing font size you must update content size of Your ScrollView.

```
int fontSize = 150;
NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'",     fontSize];
[LabelNewsContent stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
NSString *size = [LabelNewContent stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"return document.documentElement.offsetHeight"];
YOUR_SCROLL_VIEW.contentSize = CGSizeMake(YOUR_SCROLL_VIEW.contentSize.width, [size floatValue]);
```

}

You can also try (as suggested @Steve) to call:
    NSString *size = [LabelNewContent stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.offsetHeight"];

Comment: well that didnt work,the font does increase but the scrolling is disabled!

Comment: after few Nslogs it turns out that there a problem with the "return document.body.clientHeight" jscript.id be glad if anyone cud help!

Comment: thanks but i have a problem with the commas and the parentheses! xcode doesnt recognize the whole jscript as a string. I know im asking an unrelated question but do u know how to fix this?

Comment: when i NSlong "Size" it doesnt return any value,it doesn even return NULL!

Comment: `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` shouldn't include the `return` keyword.

Comment: Then what should i put instead? im not familiar with jscript at all.

Comment: @SteveWilford it can use 'return' keyword. I don't understand why it shouldn't have. I edited my answer one more time. I checked it in Web Inspector in Safari and it worked.

Comment: Try running `return 1+2` and `1+2` as the parameter to `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` and `NSLog` the result. You'll find that having the `return` keyword results in an empty string.

Comment: Even if you do something like return 1 + 2 + "";? I cannot use Xcode right now ;/

Comment: yes steve is right.i removed the return and NSlogged the result and its ok. but im still struggling with the view. the scrollview is becoming bigger in height but the webview is still cut from half.